# Sufficient Statistics for Bernoulli, Poisson, and Exponential

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

[image]

I think I solved (i)  by using the Fisher-Neyman theorem of factorization and I separated the joint likelihood into two functions, such that one, I called it h(x), does not depend on theta, only includes x, and thus I got a sufficient statistic.

I am stuck on (ii) because I don't quite understand the question and how I'm supposed to transform my answer from (i) to Bernoulli, Poisson, and Exponential. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the three, the exponential is the simplest

$$f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n; \lambda) =  \lambda e^{- \lambda x_1}\mathbb 1(x_1 \in \mathbb R_{\ge0}) \lambda e^{- \lambda x_2}\mathbb 1(x_2 \in \mathbb R_{\ge0}) \cdots\lambda e^{- \lambda x_n} \mathbb 1(x_n \in \mathbb R_{\ge0}) \\= \lambda^n \exp\left(\sum\limits_1^n -\lambda  x_i\right)\mathbb 1(x_1,x_2, \ldots,x_n \in \mathbb R_{\ge0})  \\= \exp\left(-\lambda \left(\sum\limits_1^n  x_i\right) +n\log_e(\lambda)\right)\mathbb 1(x_1,x_2, \ldots,x_n \in \mathbb R_{\ge0})$$

which is of the desired form.

The other two are similar and you should try to do them yourself